# Subir y Mostrar Imagen en C# mvc.net

Tags: c#, sql, html5, asp.net-mvc

Tengo un problema con la parte de mostrar una imagen(trabajo en MVC.NET en c# y sql), ya que quiero realizar un CRUD de un proyecto ya creado pero tengo problema con la parte de la imagen tanto para mostrarlo como editarlo, en mi base de datos la parte de "imagen y imagenLarga" esta en "varbinary (max)". Aquí está mi "modelNoticia". cuando hice con otro codigo me trajo los datos tipo texto pero menos la imagen, me sale que no lo encuentra en el servidor. Porfavor ayudenme y gracias de antemano:)

```
    using System;
    using System.Security.Principal;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

    namespace web2mayo.Models
{
    public class NoticiaModel
    {
        public NoticiaModel() {
            IdNoticia = 0;            
            TituloCorto = "";
            DescripcionCorta = "";
            Fecha = "";
            Imagen = new byte[0];
            TituloLargo = "";
            DescripcionLarga = "";
            FechaLarga = "";
            ImagenLarga = new byte[0];
    }
        public int IdNoticia { get; set; }
        public string TituloCorto { get; set; }
        public string DescripcionCorta { get; set; }
 
        public string Fecha { get; set; }

        public byte[] Imagen { get; set; }

        public string TituloLargo { get; set; }

        public string DescripcionLarga { get; set; }

        public string FechaLarga { get; set; }
  
        public byte[] ImagenLarga { get; set; }


    }
}
```

AQUI ESTA MI "NOTICIADATO"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Reflection;
using web2mayo.Models;
using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;

namespace web2mayo.Datos

{
    public class NoticiaDatos
    {
        private string error = "";
public List<NoticiaModel> BuscarNoticias()
        {
            Conexion con = new Conexion();
            List<NoticiaModel> oLista = new List<NoticiaModel>();

            try
            {
                con.conectar();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = con.getConeccion();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "WebH2Mayo.dbo.BuscarNoticias";
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FechaInicio", fechaInicio);

                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        NoticiaModel oItem = new NoticiaModel();
                        oItem.IdNoticia = reader.GetInt32("IdNoticia");

                        oItem.TituloCorto = reader.GetString("TituloCorto");
                        oItem.DescripcionCorta = reader.GetString("DescripcionCorta");
                        oItem.Fecha = reader.GetString("Fecha");

                        oItem.TituloLargo = reader.GetString("TituloLargo");
                        oItem.DescripcionLarga = reader.GetString("DescripcionLarga");
                        oItem.FechaLarga = reader.GetString("FechaLarga");

                        // Asigna los datos binarios directamente a los campos de byte[]
                        oItem.Imagen = ((byte[])reader["Imagen"]);
                        oItem.ImagenLarga = ((byte[])reader["ImagenLarga"]);

                        oLista.Add(oItem);
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }
                con.desconectar();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                error = e.Message;
                //con.desconectar();
            }

            return oLista;
        }
  }
}
```

AQUI ESTA MI CONTROLADOR

```
public class AdminNoticiaController : Controller
    {
        NoticiaDatos _NoticiaDatos = new NoticiaDatos();
        List<string> errores = new List<string>();

        private string serverRemoto = "";
        private string userRemoto = "";
        private string passRemoto = "";

        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment;

        public AdminNoticiaController(IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
        {
            _webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
            serverRemoto = builder.Build().GetSection("ConnectionStrings:ServerRemoto").Value;
            userRemoto = builder.Build().GetSection("ConnectionStrings:UserRemoto").Value;
            passRemoto = builder.Build().GetSection("ConnectionStrings:PassRemoto").Value;
        }



        public IActionResult InformacionNoticia()
        {
            if (HttpContext.Session.GetString("Logeado") == null || HttpContext.Session.GetString("Logeado") != "ok")
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
            }
            return View();
        }
        public JsonResult ListarInformacionNoticia()
        {
            List<string> errores = new List<string>();

            try
            {
                AdminDatos oDAdmin = new AdminDatos();
                string ServerFile = oDAdmin.GetParametro(1);

                NoticiaDatos oNoticia = new NoticiaDatos();
                List<NoticiaModel> lista = oNoticia.BuscarNoticias();

                // Verifica si hay errores en la consulta
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(oNoticia.getError()))
                {
                    errores.Add(oNoticia.getError());
                    return Json(new { resultado = "error", errores = errores });
                }

                // Modifica la ruta de la imagen para que sea la URL completa
                foreach (var item in lista)
                {
                    // Asegúrate de que las imágenes no sean nulas antes de formar la URL
                    if (item.Imagen != null)
                    {
                        item.Imagen = Convert.ToBase64String(item.Imagen);
                    }

                    if (item.ImagenLarga != null)
                    {
                        item.ImagenLarga = Convert.ToBase64String(item.ImagenLarga);
                    }
                }

                // Devuelve los datos y la ruta del servidor
                return Json(new { resultado = "success", lista, ServerFile });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                errores.Add("Error en el servidor: " + ex.Message);
                return Json(new { resultado = "error", errores = errores });
            }
        }
 }
}
```

EN MI CSHTML TENGO ESTO

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout_admin.cshtml";
    //ViewBag.usuario = Session["usuario"] as SistHeves.Entity.DtoUsuarioLogin;
    //ViewBag.listPermisos = Session["listPermisos"] as List<SistHeves.Entity.DtoPermisoAsignado>;
}

<div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px; margin: 5px;">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-0 col-sm-0 col-xs-0"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="padding-top: 10px; vertical-align: middle;">
        <label class="titulo" style="margin-right: 20px; padding-top: 5px;">Lista Noticia</label>
        <button class="btn btn-success form-control-s" id="btnNuevo" type="button" style="font-size: 12px; float: right;">Nueva Noticia</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-0 col-sm-0 col-xs-0"></div>
</div>
<img src="data:image/png;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Imagen)" alt="Imagen" />

<div class="row" style="margin: 0px;">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 table-responsive scrollVertical" style="height: 600px;">
        <table class="table table-striped mi-tabla" id="tblDatos">
            <thead style="position: sticky; top:0;">
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 20%; min-width: 80px;">TituloCorto</th>
                    <th style="width: 65%; min-width: 80px;">DescripcionCorta</th>
                    <th style="width: 65%; min-width: 80px;">Fecha</th>
                    <th style="width: 65%; min-width: 80px;">Imagen</th>
                    <th style="width: 65%; min-width: 80px;">DescripcionLarga</th>
                    <th style="width: 15%; min-width: 80px;">ImagenLarga</th>
                    <th style="width: 15%; min-width: 80px;">Opciones</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-0 col-sm-0 col-xs-0"></div>
</div>

<!-- Modal Nuevo -->
<div class="modal fade mi-panel" id="modalNuevo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" style="width: 100%; max-width:500px; height: auto; margin: 100px auto 10px auto;">
        <div class="modal-content" style="height: auto;">
            <div class="modal-header modal-header-busqueda">
                <label class="modal-title modal-title-busqueda" id="titulo">NUEVO</label>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body modal-body-busqueda">
                <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="frm">
                    <input type="hidden" id="id">
                    <div class="row panel-row-s">
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <label class="panel-label-busqueda">Titulo</label>
                            <div>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-s" name="titulo" id="titulo">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <label class="panel-label-busqueda">Fecha</label>
                            <div>
                            <select class="selectpicker form-control form-control-s mipanel-combo" name="Fecha" id="Fecha">
                                    <option value="0">TODOS</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <div class="row panel-row-s">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <label class="panel-label-busqueda">Descripcion</label>
                            <div>
                                <textarea class="form-control form-control-s" name="descripcion" id="descripcion" rows="3" maxlength="5000" value=""></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row panel-row-s">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 table-responsive">
                            <div style="text-align: left; margin-top: 10px;">
                                <input type="file" style="font-size:13px;" name="file" id="file" accept="application/pdf">
                            </div>
                            <div style="text-align: right; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                                <button class="btn btn-success form-control-s" id="btnGrabar" type="button" style="padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px;"><span class="icon-floppy-disk" style="margin-right: 5px;"></span> Grabar</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End Modal NUevo -->
@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/adminnoticia/Noticia.js"></script>
}
```

Y SE CREO ESTO EN JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //iniciarAnios("anio");
    //iniciarMeses("mes");
    listarArchivos();

    $("#btnNuevo").click(function () {
        iniciarFormulario();
        $("#titulo").html("NUEVO REGISTRO");
        $("#modalNuevo").modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false });
    });

});

function listarArchivos() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/AdminNoticia/ListarInformacionNoticia",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {},
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            if (data.resultado == "success") {
                $("#tblDatos tbody").html("");
                
                var tr = "";
                for (i = 0; i < data.lista.length; i++) {
                    var item = data.lista[i]; 
                    tr = "<tr>" +
                        "   <td class='celda-centrada' ><input type='hidden' value='" + item.id + "'>" + item.tituloCorto + "</td>" +
                        "   <td>" + item.descripcionCorta + "</td>" + "<td>" + item.fecha + "</td>" + "<td>" + "<img src='" + item.imagen + "' alt='Imagen'>" + "</td>" + "</td>" + "<td>" + item.descripcionLarga + "</td>" + "<td>" + item.imagenLarga + "</td>"
                    "   <td class='celda-centrada'>" +
                        "       <a href='" + data.serverFile + item.rutaArchivo + "' class='label-icono " + item.color + "' target='_blank' style='margin-right: 5px;' title='Descargar'><span class='" + item.icono + "' style='font-size: 20px;'></span></a>" +
                        "       <a href='javascript:void(0)' class='label-icono texto-naranja' style='margin-right: 5px;' title='Editar' onclick='editar(this)'><span class='icon-pencil' style='font-size: 20px;'></span></a>" +
                        "       <a href='javascript:void(0)' class='label-icono texto-rojo' title='Eliminar' onclick='eliminar(this)'><span class='icon-bin' style='font-size: 20px;'></span></a>" +
                        "   </td>" +
                        "</tr >";
                    $("#tblDatos tbody").append(tr);
                }

            } else {
                var errores = "";
                for (i = 0; i < data.errores.length; i++) {
                    errores += data.errores[i] + "<br>";
                }
                Swal.fire({ icon: 'warning', title: 'Mensaje', html: errores });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Por favor ayúdenme, y gracias de antemano:).